# Test type of input parameter of a method in OCL

Tags: uml, ocl, magic-draw

I have a class in UML that looks like this (it's in German, but I think it doesn't matter):

[image]

The first method takes an array of 4 "*Rohstoffkarte*". That's an abstract class and I have 5 concrete sub-classes for it. Now I want to check (with OCL) that all 4 instances in the array are from the same sub-class.

Any idea how to do this? I'm working with MagicDraw.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

`oclIsKindOf`, `oclIsTypeOf` to check type conformance, and use `oclType` to get the type of an object.

See OMG Object Constraint Language Specification Version 2.3.1, p.22

http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.3.1